# How to loop to get values of object in array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Updated:
Full values of `respons`:

```
"{"versions":[  
   {  
      "name":"Windows 8.1 with Update 3 (build 9600)",
      "version_id":"11"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 7 SP1 (build 7601)",
      "version_id":"9"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 10, Version 1803 - Redstone 4 [Apr 2018] (build 17134.1)",
      "version_id":"97"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 10, Version 1709 - Redstone 3 [Sep 2017] (build 16299.15)",
      "version_id":"92"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 10, Version 1703 - Redstone 2 [March 2017] (build 15063.0)",
      "version_id":"41"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 10, Version 1607 - Redstone 1 [Jul 2016] (build 14393.0)",
      "version_id":"16"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 10, Version 1511 - Threshold 2 [Nov 2015] (build 10586.0)",
      "version_id":"13"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 10, Version 1511 - Threshold 2 [Feb 2016] (build 10586.104)",
      "version_id":"14"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 10, Version 1511 - Threshold 2 [Apr 2016] (build 10586.164)",
      "version_id":"15"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Windows 10, Version 1507 - Threshold 1 [Jul 2015] (build 10240.16384)",
      "version_id":"12"
   }
]
}"
```

I have an array look like this:

```
{
   "versions":[
      {
         "name":"Windows 8.1 with Update 3 (build 9600)",
         "version_id":"11"
      },
      {
         "name":"Windows 7 SP1 (build 7601)",
         "version_id":"9"
      },
      {
         "name":"Windows 10, Version 1803 - Redstone 4 [Apr 2018] (build 17134.1)",
         "version_id":"97"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get `name` and `version_id` to add to the select dropdown.
Look like:

```
  success: function(response){
    var options = ''; 

    $(response.versions).each(function() {
        options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('version_id') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>';
    });
```

[image]

But I can't get `version_id` and `name`. Have any method to do this?

Comment: Look up jQuery each - you're using it wrong for this application - `function` accepts arguments....

Comment: eh, not necessarily wrong, just... the other version of .each would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through the array and append the generated `html` to select tag

```js
var data = {
   "versions":[
      {
         "name":"Windows 8.1 with Update 3 (build 9600)",
         "version_id":"11"
      },
      {
         "name":"Windows 7 SP1 (build 7601)",
         "version_id":"9"
      },
      {
         "name":"Windows 10, Version 1803 - Redstone 4 [Apr 2018] (build 17134.1)",
         "version_id":"97"
      }
   ]
};

data.versions.forEach(function(e){

  $("#sel").append(`<option value="${e.version_id}">${e.name}</option>`)


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel"></select>
```

Comment: It shows error looks like: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
I added Jquery 1.9.1

Comment: I add like your example. You can see at here. First: https://i.imgur.com/pl18XAi.png
second: https://i.imgur.com/S3JdnDL.png

Comment: most probably because of `response`. It would be something else. Can you do `console.log(response)` in success and let me know what is that ?

Comment: The result in console.log look like this: https://i.imgur.com/E0THzzZ.png

Comment: don't add it as an image  here. Just add the content so I could check if that's a valid json

Comment: cox the one you posted above doesn't seem to be a valid json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170194/discussion-between-vanloc-and-george-bailey).

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery for this - just iterate over the `versions` property. It's also safer to set attributes and text content directly rather than to insert text to be parsed as HTML:

```js
const input = {
  "versions": [{
      "name": "Windows 8.1 with Update 3 (build 9600)",
      "version_id": "11"
    },
    {
      "name": "Windows 7 SP1 (build 7601)",
      "version_id": "9"
    },
    {
      "name": "Windows 10, Version 1803 - Redstone 4 [Apr 2018] (build 17134.1)",
      "version_id": "97"
    }
  ]
};
const select = document.querySelector('select');
input.versions.forEach(({ name, version_id }) => {
  const option = select.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
  option.value = version_id;
  option.textContent = name;
});
```

```html
<select>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, I have error look like: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. I must using JQuery for another task. So, I tried your code and still keep Jquery. I don't know it break if JQuery is exist?

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with it - your input object must look different from the one you posted in your question if the `versions` property is interpreted to be `undefined`. Maybe edit your question to post your actual object structure?

Comment: It looks as if your `response` in `function(response){` does not actually correspond to the `response` property of the object. What are you logging in the screenshot there? Is the `response` actually the `this`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$()` and `attr()` is for reading attributes of an html element

`this` is the object, so just use object notation to access it's properties

```
 $.each(response.versions, function() {
        options += '<option value="' + this.version_id + '">' + this.name + '</option>';
 });
```

Comment: I receive error look like: `jquery.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.success (selects_for_5.js:37)
    at o (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at w (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery.js:4)`

Answer (score 1):

As others said: No need for jQuery. Not sure if jQuery can work with JSON this way as that function is primarily to access XML/DOM elements.

Here a simple ES6 version using map and reduce:

```
response.versions.map(v => `<option value="${v.version_id}">${v.name}</option>`).reduce((acc, opt) => acc + opt)
```